# Подсчёт вхождений перекрывающейся подстроки в строку

Tags: python, строки

Вхождение подстрок в строку обычно находится примерно таким образом:

```
print stroka.count("podstroka")
```

Проблема этого подхода в том, что, если у нас стоит условие найти вхождения перекрывающихся подстрок, оно работает неправильно.

Например, есть строка `"avava avavava"` и надо найти вхождения подстроки `"vav"`. Код выше даст результат 2, однако, по логике, должно быть 3, так как в начале есть `vav`, потом два вхождения в `vavav`.

Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Но ведь по логике в строке vavav одно вхождение vav. Однако если очень нужно ловить подобные случаи, то сделать не так сложно. Не трудно заметить, что в подобную ситуацию могут попадать только строки с одинаковым первым и последним символом. Можно выкидывать найденные вхождения без последнего символа из строки и проверять снова. Должно сработать.

Comment: жадный regexp должен помочь.

Comment: связанный вопрос [string count with overlapping occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2970520/4279)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот версия, которая избегает излишнего копирования входной строки:

```
def count_overlapping_substrings(haystack, needle):
    count = 0
    i = -1
    while True:
        i = haystack.find(needle, i+1)
        if i == -1:
            return count
        count += 1

print(count_overlapping_substrings('avavrewwevavavewrewrew vavvavav ', 'vav'))
# -> 6
```

Время исполнения -- квадратичное, как и у других вариантов, которые используют `str.find()` метод.

Comment: Мне тоже помог этот ответ трехлетней давности, но если вы еще тут, поясните пожалуйста, как он работает?
Разве string.find(substring) не возвращает номер  "первого вхождения"? Непонятно как именно он считает количество вхождений?

Comment: @StepanSokol подумайте какой эффект имеет второй аргумент `i+1` к `find()`.

Comment: я думаю i+1 стоящий на месте [start]  задает индекс начала среза в исходной строке, в котором требуется отыскать подстроку. Но я не понимаю, зачем это делается?

Comment: @StepanSokol запустите код в отладчике и посмотрите какие значения `i` возвращаются.    Подумайте, почему? Можно прямо в браузере на http://pythontutor.com по шагам пройти наблюдая за промежуточными значениями.

Comment: Сделал, но все равно не уловил идею, почему если старт поиска вхождения начинается с [1] индекса, то цикл находит вхождения все по очереди, даже если изменить строку и первое вхождение начнется с индекса [5], а всё то же самое, но если старт с индекса [0], то так и остается i=-1 и не хочет волшебным образом скакнуть на значение [5] соответствующее первому вхождению. Я уперся в какой-то тупик.

Comment: @StepanSokol: Попробуйте ваш вопрос в виде Stack Overflow вопроса оформить. Приведите минимальный пример кода, который у вас сложности вызывает. Соответствующие примеры ввода/вывода. Явно укажите ожидаемое по вашему поведение и явно укажите что вместо этого происходит (по шагам).  Опишите отличия.

Answer (score 5):

Можно, например, через регеспы и "lookahead":

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

def count_substrings(string, substring):
    substring_re = '(?=(%s))' %  re.escape(substring)
    return len(re.findall(substring_re, string))

print count_substrings('avavrewwevavavewrewrew vavvavav ', 'vav') # == 6
```

Причем на мелких строках он медленней, чем предложенные выше варианты, но вот начиная уже с 100 символов начинает сильно выигрывать. Я потестировал скорость, [тут](https://gist.github.com/rndD/005fa639c2b962a0e298) результаты. Регекспы в 1.23 раза быстрее. С увеличением строки эта разница будет возрастать.

Comment: достоинство, что можно `re` применять к `mmap` файлу то есть к большой строке, которой не обязательно всей в памяти сидеть: `sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'(?={})'.format(re.escape('vav')), 'avavrewwevavavewrewrew vavvavav '))` (это медленнее будет зато не ограниченно в размере)

Comment: Можно еще пооптимизировать:  

    def count_substrings(string, substring):
        if len( substring )==1:
            substring_re = re.escape( substring )
        else:
            substring_re = re.escape( substring[0] ) + "(?=" + re.escape( substring[1:] ) + ")"
        return len(re.findall(substring_re, string))

Должно дать выигрыш за счет оптимизации поиска практически до обычного посимвольного нативного поиска.  
Теоретически.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Для заданной строки [я наблюдаю гораздо меньшие отличия](https://gist.github.com/zed/62476156d065635cce0c):

    name                                 time ratio comment
    count_substrings_re_opt         17.3 usec  1.00 test_string
    count_overlapping_substrings    19.2 usec  1.11 test_string
    count_overlapping_substrings_re 19.5 usec  1.13 test_string
    count_substrings_re             22.7 usec  1.31 test_string
    count_substrings                23.2 usec  1.34 test_string

Comment: @jfs, возможно, у нас разная разрядность систем и производительность систем в целом.  
Я просто хотел показать, как можно оптимизировать регулярку и достичь бОльшей производительности.

Comment: @ReinRaus: я достаточно уверен в процедуре измерения времени (gc выключен, минимум по трём измерениям, таймер подходящий под систему (лучшее разрешение на коротких временах). Что получается [если код выполнить -- два файла скачать c самими функциями и `reporttime.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/62476156d065635cce0c)?

Answer (score 4):

Если на скорую руку, то можно так:

```
s = 'avavrewwevavavewrewrew'
ind = 1
count = 0
f = 'vav'
while ind != -1:
    ind = s.find(f)
    if ind >= 0:
        count += 1
    s = s[ind+1:]
print count
```

Суть в отбрасывании первого символа подстроки, чтобы он её больше не находил.

Comment: чтобы избежать копирования из-за `s[ind+1:]`, [можно второй параметр у `str.find` использовать](http://hashcode.ru/questions/404985#405180)

Comment: Можно в строке найти следующий, такой же, как и первый, символ и сдвигать, в случае, если он существует. Это немного ускорит программу для больших подстрок с произвольными буквами

Answer (score 0):

[[@spirit](/users/13310/spirit)](/users/13310/spirit) только ind >= 0.

```
s = 'avavrewwevavavewrewrew'
ind = 1
count = 0
f = 'vav'
while ind != -1:
    ind = s.find(f)
    if ind >= 0:
        count += 1
    s = s[ind+1:]
print count
```

Comment: согласен, так вернее. я поторопился. Без равно можно пропустить самое первое вхождение, если строка с него начинается.

Comment: Достаточно было добавить комментарий к [ответу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/405000/177596) @spirit вместо создания отдельного ответа

Answer (score 0):

```
def greed_count(str, substr):
    return 0 if len(str) < len(substr) else str.startswith(substr) + greed_count(str[1:], substr)

print(greed_count('avavrewwevavavewrewrew', 'vav'))
```

Comment: Да, но это работает раза в 2 медленнее.

Comment: Ну так разверните рекурсию в цикл. Я вообще не использую Python для задач, где нужна производительность. Python для меня - средство для создания прототипов, а также всяких полезняшек, обычно одноразовых.

Answer (score 0):

```
x="avava avavava"
a=x # переприсваивание, чтобы не потерять изначальную строку
c=0 # переменная - счётчик
while "vav" in a: # цикл, в котором мы и будем считать кол-во вхождений
    c+=1
    # замена на начало находимой подстроки 
    # если бы мы искали не vav, а vava, то замена была бы на va, а не на v
    a=a.replace("vav", "v", 1)  
print(c)
```