# Найти сколько раз 11₂ число входит в другое используя побитовые операции

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

В задаче просят найти число 11 в другом числе, используя побитовые операции. То есть ввести в любой системе счисления, программа переведет в двоичный и там посчитает. Пробовал делать но не вышло даже простое

```
a = int(input('nam: '))
c = bin(a)
b = len([i for i in c if i == '1'])
print(c)
print(b)
```

Comment: А при чем тут битовые операции?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ну, в моем примере не при чем, спросил, мб кто то знает как найти число 11 в другом числе только в двоичной системе.
(то есть, я ввожу 24 и программа находит 1 раз ее 24>11000)

Comment: А у вас и не будет работать, вы введете `"11"` в `for i in a` вам вернется 2 символа: `1` и `1`, которые конечно не совпадут с `11`. Лучше приведите в вопрос пример: какие данные вводятся, какой результат ожидается

Comment: @gil9red изменил вопрос

Comment: В общем, вопрос сводится к нахождению двоичного представления чисел и подсчету вхождения строки в другую...

Comment: @daedra Ищем перекрывающиеся вхождения?

Answer (score 6):

Приведите к бинарному виду, вот очень простой пример подсчета, его можно значительно доработать:

```
a = input("nam: ")  # например 27
b = bin(a)

print(b)  # '0b11011'

e = 0
check = b[2]
try:
    for num, i in enumerate(b[3:]):
        if i and i == check:
            e += 1
            check = b[num + 1]
        check = i
except IndexError:
    pass

print(e)
```

Или можно стандартной функцией строк посчитать вхождение подстроки:

```
b[2:].count('11')
```

Пример с побитовым сдвигом:

```
a = int(input("nam: "))  # например 27
e = 1
count = 0
while 1:
    res = a >> e
    if res % 2 == 0:
        count += 1
    e += 1

    if res == 0:
        break
print(count)
```

Comment: a = int(input("nam: "))
Спасибо за програмку

Comment: ааа, это ведь просто перевод через стандартную bin?
Разве это считается побитовым сдвигом?

Comment: Не, ну Вы хотите чтобы за вас все решили? Экзамен тоже за вас пойти сдать? Подумайте как можно сделать, отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте больше подробностей, код которые вы пишете и что не получается

Comment: @IgorSergeevich Например, если не 11, а 1 считать, то можно вообще использовать тот пример, что у меня в вопросе(я обновил там)
Но мне сказали, что нужен побитовый способ, мне бы хоть пример найти толковый, что б разобраться

Comment: Добавил побитовую операцию

Comment: это не работает. Для [15 возвращает 1](https://ideone.com/D2oOZH) (должно быть 2 или 3 так как `15=0b1111`)

Answer (score 6):

Чтобы определить содержит ли целое число во вводе два подряд идущих бита в двоичном представлении:

```
has_adjacent_bits = "11" in bin(int(input()))
```

Чтобы определить сколько раз входит "11" без перекрытия, можно [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) метод использовать:

```
>>> "-0b111".count("11")
1
```

Чтобы найти перекрывающиеся вхождения, см. [Подсчёт вхождений перекрывающейся подстроки в строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/404985/23044):

```
>>> count_overlapping_substrings("-0b111", "11")
2
```

Если хочется подсчитать количество смежных пар битов, используя побитовый сдвиг:

```
def count_overlapping_adjacent_bit_pairs(n):
    count = 0
    n = abs(n)
    while n > 0:
        count += (n & 1) & (n >> 1)
        n >>= 1
    return count
```

Это считает перекрывающиеся вхождения:

```
>>> count_overlapping_adjacent_bit_pairs(-0b111)
2
```

Чтобы посчитать сколько раз 11<sub>2</sub> входит в число:

```
def count_adjacent_bit_pairs(n):
    count = 0
    n = abs(n)
    while n > 0:
        if (n & 1) & (n >> 1): # ends with 11
           count += 1
           n >>= 1
        n >>= 1
    return count
```

Неперекрывающиеся вхождения:

```
>>> count_adjacent_bit_pairs(-0b111)
1
```

Вместо `n = abs(n)` для отрицательных чисел можно возвращать `math.inf` так как считается что бесконечное количество единиц слева ([2's complement](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)).

Comment: но просят побитовый сдвиг :)

Comment: `count += (n & 1) & (n >> 1)` точно так? не `count += (n & 3) == 3` например?

Comment: @pavel: выражение рабочее и определяет заканчивается ли число на `11`. Попробуйте все возможные 4 варианта: `00 -> 0`, `01 -> 1 & 0 = 0`, `10 -> 0 & 1 = 0`, `11 -> 1 & 1 = 1`.

Comment: @jfs да сложно как-то)

Comment: @pavel: автор просит побитовые сдвиги, я добавил побитовые сдвиги

Answer (score 0):

Пример (все числа в двоичной системе счисления):

> ```
> n            = 110101111  - установлены четыре пары битов
> n >> 1       =  11010111
> n & (n >> 1) =  10000111  - установлены четыре бита
> ```

В последнем числе установлено столько же битов, сколько было пар установленных битов в исходном числе:

```
n = int(input())
print((n & (n >> 1)).bit_count())
```

Если у вас старый Питон и нет метода `bit_count`, переведите число в строку и сосчитайте единицы в строке:

```
n = int(input())
print(bin(n & (n >> 1)).count('1'))
```