# Python поиск n-ого пробела

Tags: python

Здравствуйте, как можно получить индекс n-ого пробела в строке?

Знаю, что первый элемент можно найти с помощью метода find(" "). А как получить первый пробел с конца? Только разбиение строки на символы с помощью split() и прохождение в обратном порядке?

Comment: Поиск с конца - rfind()

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а n-ый пробел с начала или конца только циклом?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Подсчёт вхождений перекрывающейся подстроки в строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/404985/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы найти индекс `n`-ого вхождения `needle` в `haystack` строке:

```
def find_nth(haystack, needle, n):
    """Find *n*-th [overlapping] occurrence of *needle* in *haystack*."""
    i = -1
    for _ in range(n):
        i = haystack.find(needle, i + 1)
        if i == -1:
            break
    return i
```

Пример:

```
>>> haystack, needle, n = 'a b c d e', ' ', 3
>>> find_nth(haystack, needle, n)
5
```

Для проверки (тот же результат в неперекрывающемся случае):

```
>>> import re
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> next(islice((m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(needle), haystack)), n-1, None), -1)
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый пробел с конца можно получить с помощью метода [rfind()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)