# Нужно заменить каждую шестую ";" на \n

Tags: python

Пытаюсь изменить каждую шестую ";" в .csv файле на \n.
Скрипт записывает данные в одну строку в документе

```
itog = open("list.csv", 'a', encoding='utf-8')

fields = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='pdg_item_left_even')
for i in fields:
    print(i.text)

fields = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='pdg_item_even')
for x in fields:
    itog.write(x.text + ';')

time.sleep(2)
```

Как можно прочитать файл, найти  каждую 6 ";" и заменить её на \n?

Comment: возможно, вам будет полезен данный топик https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806180/python-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-n-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

Можно сразу писать в файл как нужно:

```
for i in range(0, len(fields), 6):
    itog.write(';'.join(fields[i:i+6].text))
```